# RecyclerView.Adapter, significado de inflate y bind

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Estoy empezando a programar mis primeras RecyclerView usando además el mecanismo de View Binding, y me estoy formando un cacao con los conceptos.

Mi Adaptador es este:

```
class MessagesRVAdapter(private val messagesDataSet:List<Message>):RecyclerView.Adapter<MessagesRVAdapter.MessagesViewHolder>() {
class MessagesViewHolder(view : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    //Hacemos la vinculación de la vista
    val binding = MensajeLayoutBinding.bind(view)
    //apuntamos con una variable a cada elemento del xml
    val authorImg = binding.msgImagen
    val authorName = binding.msgAuthor
    val msgBody = binding.msgBody

    fun ligar(message: Message){
        authorImg.setImageResource(message.imgAutor)
        authorName.text = message.authorName
        msgBody.text = message.text
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MessagesViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.mensaje_layout,parent, false)
    return MessagesViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = messagesDataSet.size

/**
 * Este método se llama desde el RecyclerView para que el ViewHolder asociado
 * vincule un item del modelo (un Mensaje) con su correspondiente vista
 */
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MessagesViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val message = messagesDataSet[position]
    holder.ligar(message)
}
```

}

En el onCreate se "infla" la vista a partir del xml con el layout de cada item del RecyclerView: Crea una jerarquía de objetos View a partir de una clase View creada al vuelo en tiempo de compilación (por tener activado ViewBinding).

En el onBindViewHolder entiendo que simplemente coge dato desde la clase que hace modelo y lo asigna a sus repectivas views de la vista inflada en el onCreate, en su propiedad correspondiente (texto, imagen, ...)

Si he dicho algo incorrecto a este punto corregidme, por favor.

Ahora veamos el onCreate de mi ActivityMain.kt (sin imports):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    val messagesRecycler:RecyclerView = binding.mensajesRecyclerView
    val messagesDataSet = MessagesSource.data
    messagesRecycler.adapter = MessagesRVAdapter(messagesDataSet)
}
```

Aquí, de nuevo se vuelve a llamar a un inflate. Es un inflate distinto porque no me obliga a introducir padre. Entiendo que todo eso ya está resuelto en la variable layoutinflater creada al vuelo. De nuevo corregidme si me equivoco.

La duda es, ¿por qué tras este inflado no necesito hacer un bind, y en el adaptador sí?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onBindViewHolder()` Es llamado por el `RecyclerView` para asociar una "ViewHolder" con los datos y presentar los datos que irán en la vista en una posición determinada.

> ¿por qué tras este inflado no necesito hacer un bind, y en el
> adaptador sí?

Dentro de `onCreate()` inflas inicialmente la vista que contiene el `RecyclerView`, este `RecyclerView` llamará `onBindViewHolder()` para cargar información en la vista del `RecyclerView` en una posición determinada.

La razón por la que necesitas realizas un "Bind" en el `Adapter` es por el reciclamiento y porque puedes cargar una vista o vistas diferentes, esto se realiza dentro de tu `Adapter` que en este caso es `MessagesRVAdapter()`.

En este ejemplo, en `onCreateViewHolder()` de acuerdo al tipo de vista (`viewType`) determinas que layout de tu elemento cargar, puede ser la misma u otras vistas diferentes y en onBindViewHolder() determinas la información que se cargará en esta vista.

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    var view = null
    if(viewType == 1){ //* Determina el tipo de vista.
    view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.text_row_item, viewGroup, false)
    }else{
    view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.text_row_item, viewGroup, false)
    } 

    return ViewHolder(view)
}
   
override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    
    viewHolder.textView.text = dataSet[position]
}
```

Te sugiero revisar:
[Cómo crear listas dinámicas con RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview?hl=es-419#kotlin)